# User.Claims is empty for every page outside of Areas/Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

Authorization doesn't work on Razor pages outside of Areas/Identity, cannot figure out why:

Steps to reproduce:

- Fresh app. ASP.NET Core Blazor WASM Hosted
- Create page: `Areas/Identity/Index2.cshtml`
- Create page: `Areas/NewArea/NewPage.cshtml`
- Register and Log in.
- Access `Index2` and `NewPage` and break in `OnGet` method while debugging.

  - `Index2`: property `User.Claims` **contains multiple claims**.
  - `NewPage`: property `User.Claims` **is empty**

Why the authorization is not "propagated" into `NewPage`?

When I set `@page "/Identity/NewPage"` it works so it is somehow related to Identity Area (??).

EDITS:

(Placing page into Pages folder of the server project results the same (no auth))

**Reason why do I care:**
For quick loading speed I want my index page (Index.cshtml) to be razor page (not Blazor wasm). I need to display login status on index page.

**More research:**
I have found exactly the same (unresolved, but closed) issue in aspnetcore repo. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34080

This issue describe the same scenario I have: [Authorise normal Razor Pages in a Blazor WebAssemby App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470056/authorise-normal-razor-pages-in-a-blazor-webassemby-app) and there is also a solution:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
})
```

Another same issue on SO: [Blazor WebAssembly with server side Razor page authorize problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64479243/blazor-webassembly-with-server-side-razor-page-authorize-problem)

But I still don't understand why is this happening.

**EDIT -  Solution**

The solution with changing `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` didn't work well after all - it break authorization for api controllers and wasm app.
This may be caused by my setup - I am not actually using server app for "hosting" the Blazor. Blazor app is just SPA using server app for auth and api.

Anyway: Instead of changing default schema for "everything" I change it only for particular .cshtml pages:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Identity.Application")]
```

With that ↑ everything works. But you have to paste this into every .cshtml page... Or - you can configure it in `Program.cs`:

```cs
//add policy which uses ApplicationScheme
services.AddAuthorization(config =>
{
    config.AddPolicy("RazorPagesAuthPolicy",
            policyBuilder =>
            {
policyBuilder.AddAuthenticationSchemes(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
policyBuilder.RequireAssertion(context => true);//has to be here
            });
}

//...
services.AddAuthentication()//keep this
.AddIdentityServerJwt();
//...

services.AddRazorPages(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Conventions.AddFolderApplicationModelConvention("/", mo =>
    {//add authorize and allowAnonymous filters
        mo.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("RazorPagesAuthPolicy"));
        mo.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
    }
        );
}
);
```

Comment: See if reading MSDN documentation helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: i did that you told. compiled no isssue

Comment: you should try to install newest api

Comment: That's by design...

Comment: @Nobody - Issues is not with compilation. Issues is it makes difference based on Area. I run it on newest api I can find.

Comment: @enet Why is it so and how one can overcome this?

Comment: To tell you the truth, I am not completely sure as to the reason, and wouldn't like to hazard a guess which may not be completely true. However, from my own experience, the content of the Identity folder is considered authenticated, and thus, authorized, after a user has been authenticated. Thus, when I wanted to create a User's claims DashBoard page on the server, I created it within the Identity folder without any issue. After all, if you want to create functionality on the server, because of security reasons (you don't want to expose your code to criminals, when using WebAssembly),

Comment: it is naturally functionality related to Identity, etc., so why not place it in the Identity folder. Note that you can create Razor Pages pages on the server (project) itself, in the Pages folder, but then you'll need to authenticate your user by either passing Jwt token or a cookie to the server. But I wouldn't do that like this, as it is complicated, and requires some knowledage how to implement it. Anyhow, this shows you that when you're authenticated, you're authenticated in your WebAssembly App and the Identity folder, and not in the Server project.

Comment: I'll try to find out the reason, and if succeeded I would report you. Again, I don't want a guesswork. I have some ideas, but I want something definite I can put my hands on.

Comment: @enet Thank you. I linked question which describe the same issue. And also has a solution, which I am not sure if it is way to go (??).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which I am not sure if it is way to go

As I've previously mentioned, you can either use cookies authentication or Jwt authentication in order to access the ClaimsPrincipal from the Server project. The solution proposed is fine, and it is used to configure the cookies middleware used by the identity system. Incidentally, it should be:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            }).AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

> But I still don't understand why is this happening

Do you mean why the code above works ?

The code above works because it configures the cookies middleware to authenticate the user, tells the Identity System what scheme to use, and how to challenge the user. Understand this, the Server side of your app is not authenticated, unless you configure it to perform authentication, which differs from the authentication performed when you are re-directed from the WebAssembly Blazor App. I'll try to clarify this by giving you this example:

If you created a Blazor Server App with individual accounts, and then added client SignalR to enable a chat system in your app, and you want to secure your hub object with the Authorize attribute, an authenticated user to your Blazor Server App won't be able to access secured end points on the hub, unless he is authenticated on the hub as well. How to authenticate the user ? Simply by passing the application cookie to the hub. This is more or less simialr to the issue under discussion; that is, though the Identity folder and its content are authenticated (and authorized), the hosting Server App is not.

Note: Its hard to internalized this on first shot, but rest assured that the proposed code not only works but is also 100% kosher.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution breaks authorization on api controllers when calling them from Blazor app. JWT is still the same. What has change for authorization here?

Comment: When you click on the "Fetch Data" menu item in Blazor, an HTTP call is made to retrieve data from the  protected (annotated with the Authorize attribute) WeatherForecast Controller... Do you mean that the solution interfers with such a call ? I tried, and it works perfectly well. Try it and see if it works for you. You use the HttpClient to perform API calls, right ? Any how, add to your question, a complete copy (not image) of Startup class.

Comment: Exactly like that. But I may have different condition since I am using Blazor as solely SPA (not hosted actually). I found neater solution (I think) to this whole problem. It's in question itself now.

Comment: `I am using Blazor as solely SPA (not hosted actually)` Do you mean you're using WebAssembly Blazor stand alone ? I don't think you are. Do you have a dedicated project for your Web Api controllers?

Comment: Yes. It actually is like that. I will explain: I started with hosted solution. Then I decided to dereference Blazor project from server, because of faster develop cycle (hot reloads works better, build is shorter). I set gh-action pipeline which merge it back to hosted solution (because it is easier to host them in single AppService on az). To my knowledge "original" error appeared in both "setups".  Setting `DefaultAuthenticateScheme` breaks it for SPA (probably), but I need to find (and I did actually) solution for both setups. Web api, razor pages and IdentityServer are all in Server proj.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I don't like the idea of exposing Api end points from the Server project, unless this is a small app that is not expected to scale up. If your solution solve the issues you were facing this is fine. I, however, did not have any issues with the previous settings. Anyhow, I would suggest you to take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-the-api-authentication-handler